# Queue not ordering naturally

Tags: java, queue, priority-queue

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is this strange order happens in PriorityQueue in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12369204/why-is-this-strange-order-happens-in-priorityqueue-in-java)

Please, see the code below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Queue<String> q = new PriorityQueue<String>();
    q.offer("car");
    q.offer("airplane");
    q.offer("bicycle");
    Iterator<String> i = q.iterator();
    while(i.hasNext())
        System.out.print(i.next() + " ");
}
```

Can someone explain me why the output is

```
airplane car bicycle
```

instead of

```
airplane bicycle car
```

?

Since [in the API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) it says that the elements of the priority queue are ordered according to their natural ordering.

Comment: Just found this: [Why is this strange order happens in PriorityQueue in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12369204/why-is-this-strange-order-happens-in-priorityqueue-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PriorityQueue is based on a priority heap. This data structure allows to retrieve the least element very quickly though the elements are not sorted. Adding elements to PriorityQueue is faster than to TreeSet which is tree based. Since the elements are not sorted, the iterator, as API says, "does not return the elements in any particular order".

Answer (score 9):

According to the [javadoc for the iterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#iterator%28%29):

> The iterator does not return the elements in any particular order.

However, the first item (head) is guaranteed to be the smallest. So this should print what you expect:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Queue<String> q = new PriorityQueue<String>();
    q.offer("car");
    q.offer("airplane");
    q.offer("bicycle");
    String e = null;
    while ((e = q.poll()) != null) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

If you want iteration to be sorted, you need to use a different structure, for example a `TreeSet` if you don't have duplicates.

Comment: @Lang It is probably not random - I haven't looked at the implementation, but what possibly happens when you insert a new item is that either it is smaller than the head and gets inserted first or, if not, it is put at the tail. That would explain the order you see.

Comment: But why I'm always getting that same random order? Something's up with Iterator.

Comment: (sorry my question ended up after your answer)