# PriorityQueue not sorting map by value

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap, priority-queue

I have a simple class Cell:

```
public class Cell {
    private int row, column;

    public Cell(int row, int column) {
        this.row = row;
        this.column = column;
    }

    public void setRow(int row) {
        this.row = row;
    }

    public void setColumn(int column) {
         this.column = column;
    }

    public int getRow() {
        return row;
    }

    public int getColumn() {
        return column;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
         return "[" + row + "," +  column + "]";
    }


    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + column;
        result = prime * result + row;
        return result;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Cell other = (Cell) obj;
        if (column != other.column)
            return false;
        if (row != other.row)
            return false;
        return true;
      }
}
```

I have created a HashMap. Now, I want to sort it by value. This was my approach:

```
PriorityQueue<Entry<Cell, Integer>> sortedCells = new PriorityQueue<Map.Entry<Cell, Integer>>(cells.size(), new CompareByValue());
sortedCells.addAll(cells.entrySet());
```

and CompareByValue is a Comparator:

```
private class CompareByValue implements Comparator<Map.Entry<Cell, Integer>> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Entry<Cell, Integer> lhs,
            Entry<Cell, Integer> rhs) {

        return lhs.getValue().compareTo(rhs.getValue());
    }
}
```

This `entrySet`:

```
{[1,2]=1, [1,0]=2, [2,1]=1, [-1,0]=1, [-1,1]=1, [0,2]=1, [0,-1]=1}
```

returns this `PriorityQueue`:

```
[[1,2]=1, [-1,0]=1, [2,1]=1, [1,0]=2, [-1,1]=1, [0,2]=1, [0,-1]=1]
```

Why it doesn't sort by value? I want something like:

```
[[1,0]=2, [1,2]=1, [-1,0]=1, [2,1]=1, [-1,1]=1, [0,2]=1, [0,-1]=1]
```

It's not my first time sorting a map by value using `PriorityQueue`, but I don't understand what is going on here..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is this strange order happens in PriorityQueue in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12369204/why-is-this-strange-order-happens-in-priorityqueue-in-java)

Comment: When I use poll(), elements are returned on that order. The 2-value entry should be returned first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check out the [PriorityQueue Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) you will see, that

> The Iterator provided in method iterator() is not guaranteed to traverse the elements of the priority queue in any particular order. If you need ordered traversal, consider using Arrays.sort(pq.toArray()).

But

> The queue retrieval operations poll, remove, peek, and element access the element at the >head of the queue.

Thus, if you use poll, or some of the other methods, you should get the elements in order

In order to achive a descending order of the Integers, you would have to change the comparison from

```
return lhs.getValue().compareTo(rhs.getValue());
```

to

```
return rhs.getValue().compareTo(lhs.getValue());
```

since the first orders the numbers in natural order (from smallest to largest)

Comment: I'm using poll(). And poll() should return the 2-value entry. The head element should be the largest.

Comment: that's because your comparator uses the natural ordering of numbers

Comment: I should get the elements in order, but I don't. As I said, it's not my first time using this approach (with Double instead Integer), and worked great!

Comment: i have edited my answer, please see the two return statements and adapt yours

Comment: Changing to return rhs.getValue().compareTo(lhs.getValue()); worked. Thanks man!